# Python threading events. Как запустить функцию (!) обработчик события

Tags: python, многопоточность, flask

(алёрт: я новичок в питоне)

У меня есть несколько python потоков. Один - асинхронная функция, которая получает какие-то данные. Вторая - flask приложение, на стороне которого есть обработчик, который работает с этими данными.

В краткой версии выглядит примерно так:

```
import threading 
import asyncio
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime
import queue


app = Flask('__name__')
lock = threading.Lock()

event = threading.Event()

queue = queue.Queue()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def flask_timer(): # здесь хотим обработать
    try:
        lock.acquire()
        time = queue.get()      
    finally:
        lock.release()
    print(time)
    event.set()

async def async_timer(): #получаем данные
    while True:     
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        time = datetime.now()
        print(time)
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            queue.put(str(time))
        finally:
            lock.release()
        event.wait()


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_timer())
    await asyncio.gather(task1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


class async_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
        loop.close()

class flask_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,app):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.app  = app
    def run(self):

        self.app.run()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = flask_thread(app)
    t2 = async_thread()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Насколько я понимаю (поправьте, если не прав), после первой же итерации бесконечного цикла, он зависает, ожидая, что другой поток "разбудит" его, когда обработает данные. Но этого не происходит, т.к. на стороне flask-потока некорректно (точнее вообще никак) работает функция-обработчик. Есть ли какой-то способ наладить их координацию так, что после того, как async_timer встал в режим ожидания, на стороне flask'a запускалась именно функция обработчик?

Comment: Я Вам уже отвечал на подобный вопрос. Приведите пример кода, чтобы продожить обсуждение

Comment: Добрый день/вечер. Полностью изменил вопрос в соответствии с проблемой. Извиняюсь за дубликат, впредь так делать не буду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (алёрт: я новичок в питоне)

Для новичка вы очень уж глубоко копаете. :) Это отлично!

Итак, я не трогаю Ваш `asyncio` код, единственный комментарий по нему, что секция его описания в части [Event Loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) указывает, что лучше бы Вы его не использовали, что:

> This section is intended mostly for authors of lower-level code, libraries, and frameworks, who need finer control over the event loop behavior.

**Отдельный асинхронный обработчик внутри потока Flask.**

Вообще-то, нельзя. Не стоит трогать поток Flask. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48994440/9921853), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27465533/9921853) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251898/flask-app-update-progress-bar-while-function-runs) есть обсуждения этой темы.

В Вашем коде функция `flask_timer` вообще никак не запускается - вот и не работает.

Общий вывод: используйте отдельный поток.

Таким образом, у нас есть Flask в основном потоке и два дополнительных потока для нашей задачи. На самом деле, два потока тут вроде как и не нужно - достаточно иметь поток asyncio и в нём устанавливать Event, когда задача завершена, а из функций-обработчиков запросов Flask'a можно проверять Event и забирать данные через Queue (не забывая Lock).

Вот вариант Вашего кода с двумя потоками в дополнение к Flask'у. Один получает данные у другого, и потоки обмениваются сигналами.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import asyncio
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime
import queue

app = Flask('__name__')

lock = threading.Lock()

# Два Event'a для взаимодействия, в этом случае и очередь не обязательна...
event_to_flask = threading.Event()
event_to_async = threading.Event()

queue = queue.Queue()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def flask_timer(): # здесь хотим обработать
    while True:
        event_to_flask.wait() # Ждём сигнала готовности данных
        event_to_flask.clear() # Очищаем сигнал!
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            time = queue.get() # Получаем данные
        finally:
            lock.release()
        print('Flask thread')
        print(time) # Обработка данных
        event_to_async.set() # Сообщаем, что обработка закончена и ждём новую порцию

async def async_timer(): #получаем данные
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5) # Получаем данные
        time = datetime.now()
        print('Async thread')
        print(time)
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            queue.put(str(time)) # Ставим данные в очередь
        finally:
            lock.release()
        event_to_flask.set() # Оповещаем о готовности данных
        event_to_async.wait() # Ждём сигнала, что данные обработаны
        event_to_async.clear() # Очищаем сигнал!


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_timer())
    await asyncio.gather(task1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


class async_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True # Will be stopped abruptly on program exit
    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
        loop.close()

class flask_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True # Will be stopped abruptly on program exit
    def run(self):
        flask_timer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = flask_thread()
    t2 = async_thread()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    app.run()
```

Вывод выглядит вот так:

```
Async thread
2019-04-20 21:45:13.831285
Flask thread
2019-04-20 21:45:13.831285
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2019 21:45:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2019 21:45:17] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Async thread
2019-04-20 21:45:18.840227
Flask thread
2019-04-20 21:45:18.840227
Async thread
2019-04-20 21:45:23.849117
Flask thread
2019-04-20 21:45:23.849117
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Применил все отсюда и стало работать как надо :)